# AppEngine: Switch Firestore from Native to Datastore mode

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to switch a Cloud Firestore database from 'Native' to 'Datastore mode'?

I have accidentally chosen Native mode for a websocket server running on Node, later noticing that Datastore mode is recommended for server applications. Or is it safe to use it the Native mode, if yes; then why?

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#choosing_a_database_mode):

> Warning: Once you select a database mode and execute the first write on the database, you cannot switch. You can't use both Native Mode and Datastore Mode in the same project.

In case you executed a write, you cannot switch anymore within the same project.

**EDIT:**  In the situation you did not write anything this types of switches are available:

Datastore -> Firestore in Datastore Mode

Datastore -> Firestore in Native Mode

Firestore in Datastore Mode -> Firestore in Native Mode

In your case, if you really find consider that the change would worth it, you need to create a new project.

Comment: I have not written anything to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#changing_between_native_mode_and_datastore_mode), you can change between Native mode and Datastore mode if your database is empty.

Note: This change takes a few minutes during which the database rejects all writes.

In your case, it may be worth reviewing the [behaviors](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#choosing_a_database_mode) of Native and Datastore mode to determine which suits your requirements better.